# Get Sign of a Number without Logical Statement in C#

Tags: c#, bit, sign

I want to **get the Sign of a Number without a Logical Statement**. Already a predefined method is available `Math.Sign()`. But I need to Implement in my own style.

The Tried C# Code:

```
public int GetSign(int value)
{
    int bitFlag = 1;

    var m = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
    int length = m.Length;

    if (m[length - 1] == '1')
    {
        bitFlag = -1;
    }

    return bitFlag;
}
```

Condition:

- If the Last bit is `1` then return `-1`
- If the Last bit is `0` then return `1`

Kindly assist me, how to remove the above `IF` Statement...

Comment: How the "condition" correlates with the sign of numbers and `Math.Sign()`? You're checking whether the number is odd or even, not its sign.

Comment: _"I need to Implement in my own style"_ -- why? What _specific_ problem are you trying to solve here? What's wrong with `Math.Sign()`? Are there any constraints at all on your desired alternate implementation? Why is your version so convoluted? What's wrong with `return value < 0 ? -1 : (value > 0 ? 1 : 0);` (i.e. why _"without a logical statement"_)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting thing about bit shifting:
If you right shift the bits, the leading bit will be propagated to the right.

Example byte : 10000000
Example byte >> 1 : 11000000

Integers take 32 bits to represent. So what happens if we shift the bits by 31 places? The leading bit will always be propagated, meaning all positive numbers will become 0 and all negative numbers will become -1.

Therefore :

```
public static int signOfInt(int input)
{
    return (input >> 31);
}
```

will return 0 for positive numbers and -1 for negative numbers.

Comment: To precisely match the conditions of the question, it would need to be `return 2 * (input >> 31) + 1;` but I suppose that last part is trivial given that the answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
public int GetSign(int value)
{
    return -(((value & 1) << 1) - 1);
}
```